# Ubuntu/ROS not recognizing Turtlebot 2/USB device

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Turtlebot 2 that I am currently having a lot of issues with. I was able to successfully install Ubuntu on my computer, install ROS and test the installation of ROS (through this tutorial http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/6/). The problem I´m having is that Ubuntu does not recognize Turtlebot through the USB cable. Ubuntu does recognize other pen drives but not Turtlebot. I have plugged the Turtlebot into other computers and it is recognized in Windows. So I believe this is isolated to a software issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227475/ubuntu/ros-not-recognizing-turtlebot-2/usb-device/) by [kmattingly](https://answers.ros.org/users/26062/kmattingly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
Please provide output of `lsusb -v` command.

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
Have you tried [turtlebot  tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/hydro/TurtleBot%20Bringup)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also check the permissions of the USB. If I remember correctly, I had to set up a udev rule to automatically set permissions.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0